# Docker not working on Pi 5 running Pi OS on NVMe SSD

Tags: docker, pi-5, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, pci

## Issue

I'm trying to get CasaOS working on my Raspberry Pi 5 but I seem to be having compatibility issues with Docker. Basically when I install CasaOS on Ubuntu it works but if I try install CasaOS on Pi OS I get all kinds of errors in docker saying that it can't access gitlab etc.

## Hardware:

- Raspberry Pi 5
- Geekworm X1001 Pcie M.2 Key-M NVMe SSD PIP PCIe Peripheral Board for Raspberry Pi 5
- Curcial P3 Plus 512gb NVMe M.2 SSD

## CasaOS on Pi OS on Pi5

*Fresh install of `Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64-bit)`*

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot
curl -fsSL https://get.casaos.io | sudo bash
sudo reboot
sudo docker run hello-world
```

*Ouput*

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
docker: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/sha256:2d4e459f4ecb5329407ae3e47cbc107a2fbace221354ca75960af4c047b3cb13": dial tcp [2600:1f18:2148:bc02:445d:9ace:d20b:c303]:443: connect: network is unreachable.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

## Docker on PI OS

*Fresh install of `Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64-bit)`*

https://github.com/slowrunner/wali_pi5/ ... pt_repo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# REF:https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-repository 

# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```

https://github.com/slowrunner/wali_pi5/blob/main/configs/docker/2_install_docker_pkgs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
sudo docker run hello-world
```

*Output*

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
docker: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/sha256:2d4e459f4ecb5329407ae3e47cbc107a2fbace221354ca75960af4c047b3cb13": dial tcp [2600:1f18:2148:bc02:445d:9ace:d20b:c303]:443: connect: network is unreachable.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

## More info

In both examples, there are no errors when installing docker but it just fails to work correctly.

I will mention that I tried flashing the drive with Ubuntu Server from the Pi imager and installed CasaOS and it worked perfectly!

I don't like Ubuntu though for 3 reasons.

1. The install size is bigger
2. It constantly spits out warning messages about some Bluetooth problem
3. I can't connect with SSH to the ethernet address. Only WLAN

I have to stress that I'm pretty new to Linux so I don't really know what I'm doing but I would really appreciate some help and some patience if I don't understand right away.

Comment: Welcome. You get the "network is unreachable" bit, right?  What if you try "https://registry-1.docker.io" in a browser (or `wget`)?  It will return a 404, but this at least demonstrates the site is reachable.  Some of your 1 2 3 about ubuntu makes this seem like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)... If you'd rather use RpiOS that's fine (it is a better choice for beginners on the Pi) but if you keep distro hopping to avoid problem solving you'll be at it forever.